# Why does my websocket server always report [websocket: control frame length > 125]?

Tags: ios, websocket, gorilla, socketrocket

My iOS application uses `SocketRocket` to establish a connection with my websocket server. But after establishing a connection and sending the first message, the server (using `gorilla/websocket`) tries to parse the frame, but failed:

```
message_type, r, err := ws.NextReader()
if err != nil {
    goto end
}
```

An error is reported when calling NextReader():

```
Websocket Read Failed: [websocket: control frame length > 125]
```

The strange thing is, I use `SocketRocket`'s `send()` method to send data, so there should never be any control frames (ping/pong).

Has anyone seen this problem before? Help!

Comment: If the bits 9 to 15 are interpreted as unsigned int are 125 or less thats your length, if not you need to add more bits to determine the data length. You are using SocketRocket, so I guess you are not doing anything with the Websocket frames, right?